# Explicação sobre pub sub(redis)

Tags: redis

Pesquisei sobre **pub sub** e não encontrei nada em português, então resolvi perguntar aqui, queria entender como funciona o **pub** e **sub** especialmente para ser aplicado com o **redis**, li algo sobre, mas não consegui compreender muito bem como funciona.

Seria criar canais em que os usuários pudesse se inscrever, e todos inscritos nesse canal poderia ler a mensagem? por exemplo um jogo onde é compartilhado a posição dos objetos e dos jogadores, esses canais poderiam ser então áreas do mapa que seriam criados a partir que fossem aparecendo jogadores online. Onde ficaria os dados?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Os dados ficam na memória do servidor, eventualmente armazenados em disco de acordo com as configurações do redis. Quando um cliente recebe os dados, fica na memória do cliente até você fazer alguma coisa com aquele dado.

PubSub é um mecanismo de notificações em tempo real. Acho que você já está com uma ideia boa sobre isso.

Num sistema de notificações, por exemplo um chat, João e Maria estão numa conversa direta. O cliente de Alex não precisa receber as notificações da conversa deles, então o PubSub vai ajudar a resolver esse problema. Com ele, é possível criar canais de publicação de notificações (*Pub*), e então você inscreve neles os clientes que devem recebê-las (*Subs*), apenas para segregar por qualquer critério as notificações para os clientes. No chat, você poderia criar um canal PubSub "JoãoxMaria" em que apenas o cliente de ambos está inscrito. Há um chat público em que todos podem conversar entre si, então essas notificações todo mundo deve receber, nesse caso todos estão inscritos (*Sub*scripted) nesse canal de publicação (*Pub*).

A diferença do PubSub para outros métodos de transmissão é que você não está especificando cada inscrito ao enviar uma mensagem, está simplesmente especificando o canal, sem saber quais são os inscritos (nem saber se há inscritos). As vantagens são maior escalabilidade e menor acoplamento (publicadores não precisam saber sobre os inscritos).

Você pode brincar um pouco no terminal para testar isso, veja:

[image: asciicast]

Comment: Então era mesmo o que eu estava pensando, será uma boa para mim, estou construindo o multiplayer para um jogo, e preciso compartilhar informações entre os players, mas seria inviável compartilhar tudo com todo mundo, mas posso criar esses canais de pequenas áreas em volta dos players, e quem fosse entrando e saindo dessa área iria ser inscrito ou retirado do canal, minha pergunta é: criar e excluir canais é simples como se inscrever neles? pois com um tempo seria preciso "limpar" a partir que não tivesse mais ninguém na área do canal por muito tempo.

Comment: E como eu faria esse controle? os jogadores enviariam sua posição para o canal com um PUBLISH? isso não entendi muito bem, ou para o armazenamento, seja em cache seja em disco, e o canais pegariam a partir dai? como faria para esses canais pegar essa informação, não consigo visualizar isso. Tentar aqui: Maria é um player, está online, então uma área em volta dela será criada como um canal, onde especificaria quais informações iriam para Maria, apenas um exemplo, todos inimigos que estão nessa área? João entrou na área do canal, agora também recebe essas informações e também a pos de Maria...

Comment: Eu crio o canal quando digito "SUBSCRIBE todos". Se não existe, cria e se inscreve. Se já existe, apenas se inscreve. Eu não fiz nada antes de começar a gravar o asciinema, aquilo é direto após iniciar o server do redis. Não faço ideia de se isso seria apropriado num multiplayer online. Acho que depende muito do jogo, mas não tenho experiência com isso.

Comment: mas ali você envia a mensagem diretamente do canal, e se joão quer enviar uma mensagem? tipo vai para o canal e depois para todos do canal? como é isso?

Comment: @PerduGames To mandando todas as mensagem direto de outro redis-cli, só pra mostrar o PUBLISH, sem me preocupar com “quem” está mandando. No sentido horário, os três primeiros painéis são clientes do redis inscritos em canais e no último painel estou mandando mensagens. Pra identificar o autor, você precisaria formar uma mensagem tipo: `{autor_id: 1, message: "olá"}`. O redis é completamente alheio a essas coisas, ele só entrega e recebe mensagens.

Comment: Não tem sistema de usuários no redis, você teria que implantar como metadados das mensagens, entendeu? em todos os 4 terminais, o ambiente é o mesmo: um redis-cli

Comment: então penso que deveria enviar as informações dos clientes que estão em um canal para algum lugar e de la transmitir para todo o canal. Seria isso?

Comment: @PerduGames O que estaria tentando realizar com isso?

Comment: não estou conseguindo entender, como seria feito o envio das mensagens, joão envia uma mensagem e ela vai para onde? como ela vai para o canal para ir para todos do canal?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67469/discussion-between-rodorgas-and-perdugames).

Comment: não to entendendo se a sua pergunta tem a ver com o mecanismo de transporte ou distribuição do redis, ou apenas o uso

Comment: uma dúvida rápida que me veio, se quero poder ter vários usuários e canais, preciso então para cada usuário criar um cliente no redis para se inscrever no canal, certo? e como faria para receber as mensagens? tentei assim, mas não creio que seja assim pois não funcionou. `clients[userID]['cliRedis'].on("message", function(channel, message) {...});` teria que fazer um loop pelos clientes?

Comment: Aí tem a ver com alguma implementação, alguma linguagem específica e biblioteca específica. Abra uma nova pergunta.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/248871/escutar-mensagens-com-v%C3%A1rios-clientepub-sub-redis feita