# Escutar mensagens com vários clientes(pub/sub)

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, redis

Se quero poder ter vários usuários e canais, preciso então para cada usuário criar um cliente no redis(ou seja qual for o pub/sub utilizado) para se inscrever no canal? e como faria para receber as mensagens? estou pensando assim, os clientes redis-pub/sub precisariam estar no nível em que está o servidor websocket, pois a comunicação cliente servidor seria apenas por websocket, não sei o que pub/sub utiliza para comunicação, mas estou querendo apenas websocket entre cliente e servidor, e o redis(banco de dados + pub/sub) comunicando localmente dentro do servidor:

```
'use strict';

//CREATE WEB SERVER
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
//CREATE WS
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server: http, port: 8080 });
//CREATE REDIS
var redis = require('redis');
var redisClient = redis.createClient({host : 'localhost', port : 6379});

var clients = {};

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
    ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
         // Aqui dependendo de certa mensagem recebida,
         // como um login por exemplo, eu faria algo assim:
         ws['user'] = obj.login.user.toString();
         //CRIAR UM NOVO CLIENTE REDIS SUBS
        clients[obj.login.user.toString()]['cliRedis'] = redis.createClient({host : 'localhost', port : 6379});
        // SE INSCREVER NO CANAL 
        clients[obj.login.user.toString()]['cliRedis'].subscribe();
    });

   if("user" in ws) {
        clients[ws.user]['cliRedis'].on("message", function(channel, message) {
             console.log("Msg on subscriber: " + message);
             //aqui enviaria os dados por websocket para o cliente
        });
   }
});
```

> **Up 1:**

Com a resposta e comentários do @rodorgas consegui esclarecer bastante o que tenho a fazer. Então cheguei a conclusão que existem duas possibilidades,  para os vários clientes poderem escutar as mensagens enviados pelo sistema pub/sub:

1 - Utilizando o Centrifugo como indicado na resposta do @rodorgas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

2 - Utilizando o redis pub/sub:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comparações:

A maneira 1 teria quer ter duas conexões websockets ativas, uma para o Centrifugo e outra para o ws-server, pelo menos não encontrei nada na documentação do Centrifugo em que eu possa tratar mensagens que não sejam especificas para o pub/sub, algo como **centrifugo-server.on("menssage"**, então penso que seria mesmo necessário duas conexões websockect nesse modo. Então ambos gastariam praticamente a mesma quantidade de sockets, pois os sockets necessários para a comunicação do redis pub/sub que seriam ganhos utilizando a maneira 1, são perdidos tendo que abrir uma nova conexão para a comunicação com o client-godot. A vantagem da maneira 1 é que parece ser de mais fácil entendimento, pois o client pub/sub está mesmo no cliente, que até nem existe de verdade, porque o Centrifugo apenas requer mensagens por websocket, não existe um cli-Centrifugo como existe um cli-redis, o client-Centrifugo é apenas o client-godot enviando mensagens via websocket. Já a maneira 2 os clientes-redis estariam armazenados dentro de um objeto javascript no script do nodejs. A maneira 1 eu terei que enviar as mensagens no padrão do Centrifugo que são grandinhas comparado ao que posso fazer enviando da maneira 2.

Enfim, estou indeciso de qual modo começar implementar, talvez faça os dois e escolha o que for mais rápido. De qualquer forma estou sem tempo nos próximos dias para começar a trabalhar nisso, então ainda tenho tempo para pensar no que fazer.

> **Conclusão:**

Escolhi implementar com o redis pub/sub, pelo que estudei eu teria mais controle sobre o que estou fazendo. Porém não descartei o Centrifugo, ele me servirá muito bem caso eu venha implementar um chat no jogo, pois ele é muito bom para essa tarefa, com ele tenho como, por exemplo, criar conversas privadas entre apenas dois clientes, entre outras facilidades que já vem implementadas para você utilizar.

Comment: Você quer distribuir as mensagens para pessoas através do navegador? Não sei como o pubsub do redis vai te ajudar nisso, pois não é uma tecnologia web. Seria útil se você quisesse distribuir mensagens para servidores ou aplicativos nativos. No que parece ser o seu caso, só o websocket é suficiente. E talvez você queira usar o `socket.io` ao invés do `ws` (pois o socket.io implementa vários fallbacks).

Comment: acho que não consegui passar o que quero muito bem, as mensagens do pub/sub não iriam diretamente para o cliente, ali chegaria a mensagem e por websocket iria para o cliente, irei até editar.

Comment: O que quero: criar canais que são "pedaços do mapa" e todos os jogadores que estiverem nesse pedaço, ouvirão as mensagens desse canal, minha duvida é se estou fazendo certo acima, criando os clientes e armazenando no script do server. Seria: cliente envia mensagem por websocket para o server, o server salva no banco de dados/cache, cliente entra em um canal onde ficará escutando as mensagens, redis pub/sub envia mensagem buscada no banco de dados/cache, e assim é enviado via websocket para o cliente.

Comment: Em " cliente envia mensagem por websocket", o cliente é o navegador. Em "cliente entra em um canal …", o cliente é o servidor em node-js. Tá confuso. Mas acho que é isso mesmo.

Comment: me desculpe, está mesmo. Sim em "cliente envia mensagem por webscoket" ele é o navegador. E "cliente entra em um canal" ele é o cliente redis que está no servidor mesmo, dentro de `var clients`, e ai é que entra dúvida, tenho mesmo que criar um cliente redis para cada cliente websocket?

Comment: As duas questões. **1 -** Tenho mesmo que criar um cliente redis para cada cliente websocket? se sim, entra a questão **2 -** A maneira(`... clients[ws.user]['cliRedis'].on("message" ...`) como estou escutando as mensagens acima está correta?

Comment: 1. Tem certeza que você precisa de redis/pubsub? Quem vai gerar as mensagens? Você pode enviar mensagens websocket direto do backend, usando várias linguagens. Pelo objetivo que você descreveu, eu não usaria redis não. Dê uma olhada no diagrama do [centrifugo](https://fzambia.gitbooks.io/centrifugal/content/), não é só isso que você precisa? Claro que dá pra fazer usando redis mas parece uma volta em circulos, talvez eu não esteja entendendo sua arquitetura. Quem vai gerar as mensagens? 2. Não tenho experiência com essa biblioteca.

Comment: eu já estou utilizando redis como cache para as informações, o pub/sub seria para os canais, é preciso, se não teria que enviar mensagem de atualização da posição de todos online no servidor para todo mundo, o que seria ruim.

Comment: Tenho o cliente-jogo(pode chamar de navegador) que se conecta ao servidor, quando isso acontece, é criado um cli-redis para ele, o cliente-jogo envia sua posição para o servidor por websocket, então o servidor salva no redis essa informação, o cli-redis se inscreve em um canal que é a área ao redor dele, assim só lhe interessa informações dessa área, evitando informações desnecessárias de serem enviadas. Outro cliente-jogo se conecta na mesma área, cria outro cli-redis para ele, que entrará no mesmo canal, assim cada um recebe a posição do outro, sincronizando suas posições no jogo.

Answer (score 1):

O [Centrifugo](https://fzambia.gitbooks.io/centrifugal/content/index.html) é um servidor pubsub, ele "cria canais" no websocket (na verdade é uma camada de abstração, ele cuida dos usuários singulares e permite que você agrupe-os em canais). Isso sem ter o redis como intermediário.

Então vamos supor que seu mapa é dividido em setores. A intenção é entregar uma mensagem para milhares de jogadores que estão no setor (1,1) do mapa. Coloque assim no navegador:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var centrifuge = new Centrifuge({
        url: 'http://localhost:8000/connection',
        user: "USER ID",
        timestamp: "UNIX TIMESTAMP SECONDS",
        token: "SHA-256 HMAC TOKEN"
    });

    // inscreva o usuário no setor correspondente
    centrifuge.subscribe("(1,1)", function(message) {
        console.log(message);
    });

    centrifuge.connect();

</script>
```

No backend, no lado do servidor. Emita uma mensagem assim (to assumindo backend em nodejs, mas o centrifugo suporta várias linguagens):

```
Client = require("jscent");

var c = new Client({url: "http://localhost:8000", secret: "secret"});

c.publish("(1,1)", {"input": "test"}, function(err, resp){console.log(err, resp)});
```

Quando seu jogo estiver enorme e você tiver muitos servidores, você coloca o redis na parada. O Centrifugo usa o redis para fazer load balancing, por exemplo, em situações com alta escala.

Talvez alguém surja com uma ideia usando o redis no meio. Mas eu tô vendo que o redis sempre vai ficar no meio: você vai precisar passar para o navegador depois. O Centrifugo realmente já resolve isso numa tacada só. Eu usaria ele.

Comment: agora entendi, mas não daria para mim usar o Centrifugo, porque o cliente-jogo na verdade não é um navegador, disse "navegador" apenas para ficar mais claro que não era o cliente-redis, então não existiria essa biblioteca Centrifugo, o cliente estou fazendo na godot(game engine), a não ser que eu faça um módulo para o centrifugo, mas como já salvo os dados do cliente no redis, acho que seria muito trabalho fazer um modulo para isso, por isso tive a ideia de utilizar os cli-redis no backend.

Comment: Mas esse godot suporta websockets? Suporta javascript? Você programa nele em que linguagem?

Comment: não, estou tendo que utilizar um modulo para websocket, mas na godot 3 ficarão de implementar webscoket. Não suporta javascript, ela utiliza uma linguagem própria de script chamada GDScript. Eu havia pensado em fazer dessa maneira, colocando os cli-redis no cliente-jogo. Porém teria que criar um módulo para isso também, por isso lidar com os cli-redis no backend.

Comment: Olha o que ele fala aqui "Connections can use pure Websockets protocol" não precisa do centrifuge.js https://fzambia.gitbooks.io/centrifugal/content/server/index.html Se você realmente não quer usar o centrifugo, você basicamente vai acabar reescrevendo algo igual ao que ele já faz. Pelo menos pode olhar no código-fonte e copiar um pouco hehe.

Comment: E desta maneira utilizando o Centrifugo, os dados não estão sendo salvos, o que preciso também, de qualquer forma preciso enviar para um banco de dados primeiro.

Comment: O pubsub do redis não salva nada, anyway

Comment: sim, mas o redis sim, estou enviando informações para o redis cache/persistência, onde busco para enviar para os clientes com o pubsub.

Comment: Você não consegue enviar para o redis e para o centrifugo simultaneamente?

Comment: é isso que pensei agora, e estava digitando kkkkk é o que daria para fazer, e talvez seria mais rápido. Mas teria um problema, as vezes precisaria ir buscar no banco de dados e enviar para o Centrifugo do mesmo jeito, nem tudo estaria sempre acessível na cena do jogo. O projeto tem extrema necessidade de um banco de dados, pois gero tudo por ruídos e as mudanças ficam salvas no redis. Acho que não tem jeito, vai ter que ir no banco de qualquer maneira, por isso escolhi o redis, pelo menos estaria em memória, mas rápido.

Comment: tipo aqui `c.publish("(1,1)",{` onde pegaria a informação para enviar para o canal? é ai que entra o redis banco de dados, porém utilizando o  Centrifugo, eu não precisaria ter o trabalho todo com o redis pub/sub, sockets a menos sendo utilizado, já que o Centrifugo envia via websocket. De qualquer forma o redis estaria lá como cache/bd, mas prefiro mesmo deixar o cliente no cliente. Vou estudar esse Centrifugo, acho que vou usar ele. Funciona como o redis pub/sub para se inscrever/excluir etc nos canais? porque precisaria mudar várias vezes, já que o players se movimentam e mudam de canal.

Comment: o problema de utilizar Centrifugo é que as mensagem que ele envia/recebe são grandes demais. Com pub/sub do redis eu teria controle sobre como criar a mensagem, e reduziria o máximo. Com ele perco esse controle, porque tenho que seguir o padrão dele, mas se não atrapalhar eu não ligo, tenho que testar e ver como vai ser. Acho que vou implementar das duas maneiras, utilizando o redis pub/sub e o Centrifugo, o que ficar melhor eu utilizo.